# What is the generated data in the Google-cloud-composer source bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

What is this data in google-cloud-composer's source bucket?

Is it safe to delete?

Is there a way to hide it or make it stop generating?

It's making my environment ugly.

[image: ![What is this data]

Comment: It looks like they are records for update operations done to the Cloud Composer environment (open those files in a text editor to see what I mean). There is no mention of their presence in the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage). I've reached out to Google Cloud Support for clarification on their purpose, will update here when I get a response. Unless someone else beats me to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files you referred are created when  Composer performs an operation. For this reason, they can be deleted safely when no operations are in-flight, and are not an indicator of potential issues in an environment.

Comment: Do you know of a quick way to delete them after composer runs? If not I may need to write something to do that.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#console), there are a few ways of deleting objects from your GCS Bucket. Although, be careful just to delete the files we discussed.